# Uglify JS beautify using tabs

Tags: javascript, code-formatting, uglifyjs

I know I can set the indent level of javascript that has been beautified with uglifyjs, but is it possible to get it to use tabs instead of spaces?

If not, Is there a similar tool that can? Or any patched version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Uglify JS's `process.js` file just modify the [`indent`](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/v1.3.5/lib/process.js#L1525) function so instead of space (`" "`) it inserts tabs (`"\t"`).

Answer (score 0):

Use [JS beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). Just set it to use tabs for indent.

Answer (score 0):

Try Escodegen.
https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen/wiki/API

```
      indent: {
          style: '    ',
          base: 0,
          adjustMultilineComment: false
      },
```